# How can I transfer a file over ethernet on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ethernet

I am trying to transfer a 3GB file from a Ubuntu machine to a MacBook I tried doing it over Wi-Fi but it was taking to long so I went and connect them via ethernet but when I try to connect the machines, neither of them recognize the other one I have tried using samba and NitroShare but the same happens in both.
since neither of them has an Ethernet and I am using a USB 3.0 to ethernet on the Ubuntu machine and a thunderbolt to ethernet in the mac I first thought it was a driver or issue but when I enter to the network configuration on any of the computers show the wired connection.
This is the first time I try something like this on a linux machine but I have done it before between Windows and Mac computers without any problem.
I really would like some  help and advise

Comment: Start with networking: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1266718/edit) to show us that you have put them on the same network.

Comment: You can try to install SSH server on linux and try to connect from mac using inbuilt sftp in terminal or any other sftp client GUI.

Comment: Have you directly connected the two computers, or have used some router. As suggested by @user535733, it is very much necessary to know how you have connected the two computers through ethernet.